# What is Outlook version 1.2023? Does it support MAPI?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Our program will invoke MAPI in Outlook to perform tasks.

Today one of our customers said our program cannot work with his Outlook, and he give the Outlook version as below:

[image]

I have never seen such an Outlook version, as it is usually to be Outlook 2019, Outlook 2021, etc.

So just wonder what is this Outlook and does it fully support MAPI?

Comment: Could be the Windows Store version of outlook, probably a cut down version that according to reviews is basically the same as the web app https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/outlook-for-windows/9NRX63209R7B?ocid=cmmvxm26rjh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the new Outlook version that Microsoft intends to be the
replacement for Mail and Calendar whose support will stop end of 2024.

See the article
[The New Outlook for Windows is Coming in August](https://www.howtogeek.com/the-new-outlook-for-windows-is-coming-in-august/):

> The new Outlook for Windows is based on the Outlook.com web app, with an overhauled design and improved integration with other Microsoft 365 services. It has a more modern appearance, matching the Fluent design language used across Windows 11, the new Microsoft Teams, and other Microsoft software. It also has both light and dark modes, so no matter which mode your PC is using, Outlook should fit right in.

This new version still has many issues, as listed in the article
[Avoid The New Outlook](https://www.nsa-nv.com/new-outlook/).

If your app is not supported in this new version, you will need
to debug and adapt it.